# calling a function in jquery issue

Tags: jquery, dhtml

I am trying to call my function loadPopup() although failing using JQuery v1.3.2.
any suggestions?
many thanks,

```
$(this).find("a").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected") == false) {

        $(this).css("background-color", "#efefef");
        alert(1);
        loadPopup();
        alert(2);                     

    }
})

function loadPopup() {
    alert("");       
}
```

Comment: "Failing" isn't very helpful, what's it doing, not doing?

Comment: the alert in loadPopup() is never displayed.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, didnt paste the whole thing.

```
          $(this).find("a").each(function(i) {
              if ($(this).hasClass("selected") == false) {

                  $(this).css("background-color", "#efefef");
                  alert(1);
                  loadPopup();
                  alert(2);                     

              }
          })
```

Comment: Don't post this as an answer. Edit your original question.

Comment: ok sorry, couldnt see where to edit..  see the html here http://jamesradford.net/so/demo.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting at the root looking for all `<a>` links, you should replace this:

```
$(this).find("a").each(function(i) {
```

with this:

```
$("a").each(function(i) {
```

And you can further slim it down by using selectors to your advantage.  In this case combine the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with the [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to get all `<a>` without the class, like this:

```
$("a:not(.selected)").css("background-color", "#efefef").each(function() {
  loadPopup();
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DFsBJ/).

Comment: wow, whats this..(?) I need to call the loadPopup when hovering over any of the 6 divs.

Comment: @James - Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DFsBJ/1/ (uncomment out the alert to see that it works)

Comment: i need the corresponding UrgencyMessage div to become visible when hovering over any of the 6 boxes.

Comment: @James - I'm not sure *exactly* what you're after on the background color, this can probably be done in CSS, but this should work for the `<div>` showing: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DFsBJ/3/

Comment: thank you, that is what I want but can you see how the popup is cut shot because of the overflow: hidden property on OutboundDaySliderContainer? -- this is the problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: @James - Just remove the `overflow: hidden` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DFsBJ/4/

Comment: we need to keep the overflow: hidden property..  hence the problem.

Comment: @James - what about a fixed position then: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DFsBJ/5/

Comment: it needs to stay hidden because on the left and right we have additional boxes that are scrolled into view on the users request.

Comment: @James - Check out the demos section here: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/05/jquery-ui-19m1-tooltip/

Comment: @James - there are *many* tooltip plugins, and most have a 1.3.2 version as well, for example: http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/

Comment: looks like this might be the best bet but im strugglying to get text into the popup except for hard coding it into the content: 'hello' property   http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials/#position

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not binding any event on the *href*. Thats the reason, even on click of the link, your `loadPopup()` is not being called.

I hope the following code can help you out :

```
$(this).find('A.selected').unbind('click').bind('click',function() { 
    loadPopup();

    });
```

You can place either $(this) in above code, if you are querying inside table row etc. collections or you can use directly : `$('A.selected').unbind`.....